# InfiniteScroll - How to reset all grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am using InfiniteScroll:

```
var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( '.grid', {
  path: function() {

    var pageNumber = ( this.loadCount + 1 );

    var apiUrlQuery = $('.pagination__next').attr('href') + '&page=' + pageNumber;

    return apiUrlQuery;
  },
  responseType: 'text',
  status: '.scroll-status',
  history: false
});
```

But now I need to implement search, so that means I need to refresh the path and the grid. How to do it?

So far what I have done is:

```
$('.search-events').on('click', function() {

  infScroll.destroy();

  /* building search query */

  $('.grid-item').remove(); //Remove items visually from the grid

  var apiUrlQuery = baseUrl + "&" + searchBy + "=" + searchTerm;
  $('.pagination__next').attr('href', apiUrlQuery); //Update search url

    infScroll.create();

    infScroll.isLoading = false;

    infScroll.loadNextPage();
})
```

With this, I am doing a new request using a new URL and get results but they don't get printed on the screen, also I see that the height of the grid is still the same as if I did not remove the grid-items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work:

```
$('.search-events').on('click', function() {
   msnry.remove($('.grid').find('.grid-item'));
   var apiUrlQuery = baseUrl + "&" + searchBy + "=" + searchTerm;

    $('.pagination__next').attr('href', apiUrlQuery);

    infScroll.isLoading = false;
    infScroll.canLoad = true;
    infScroll.create();

    msnry.layout();

    infScroll.loadNextPage();
})
```

This line removes the elements from the DOM as I did with $('.grid-item').remove(), but also remove it from some internal array that keeps data.

```
msnry.remove($('.grid').find('.grid-item'));
```

Also, I removed infScroll.destroy(); because it unbinds from the load method.

The key part is msnry.layout(); this one rebuilds the layout.

Hope it helps someone in the future.